# FOP/itext | PDF Accessibility | Set Language of Document

Tags: itext, xsl-fo

I am generating a PDF document from an XML using XSL template in Apache FOP API. My applications requires the PDF documents to be generated dynamically.

Now, I need to set the language of the document to English (which defaults to x:unknown). How can I add this meta-info using XSL-FO or i-text?

Comment: Setting the language isn't the only thing you need to do when making a PDF accessible (accessible PDF is PDF/UA). Please read my answer to the question [How can I generate a PDF/UA compatible PDF with iText?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-generate-pdfua-compatible-pdf-itext) You'd also benefit from reading [the book about ZUGFeRD](http://developers.itextpdf.com/books). It's about making invoices, but it also explains how to create PDF/UA based on invoices created in HTML (which is originally generated from XML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `xml:lang` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#xml.lang).  E.g.:

```
<fo:root xml:lang="en" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
```

(You don't need a namespace declaration for the `xml` prefix because it's known to every XML processor.)